# innerhtml firefox not working with Doc type

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function selectSomething(){
    var obj = document.all.select1;
    var selectValue = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value;

    if(selectValue == "1"){
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML ="one";
    }
    if(selectValue == "2"){
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML ="two";
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="selectSomething()">

<select id="select1" onchange="selectSomething()">
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
</select>

<div id="text"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

This code works in Chrome 17.0.963.83, IE 8.0.6001.18702, but does not work in Firefox 11.0.  The innerhtml never shows in Firefox unless I remove the DOCTYPE which I cannot do because this webpage will be part of a larger project.  Is this a Firefox bug?  How do I make this work in Firefox?

Comment: Why do you have a FRAMESET doctype?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the Firefox error console (really useful for web developers). In Firefox, `document.all` is undefined.

Instead, you should use `document.getElementById("select1")`.

Comment: Just loaded it and saw the "document.all is undefined  var obj = document.all.select1;" error.  Made the switch like you said and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: @bitnuk3r: Glad to hear it. I find it to be the best practice to start out your development in Firefox (more standards-compliant than IE) and then perform any adjustments needed to make it work in other browsers. A very useful Firefox add-on for web developers is [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

Comment: Yeah, I should have checked it before I posted.  I guess when I see an error my gut instinct is to "StackO it" since the community here is so great and solutions are posted so quickly.  Thanks again.  Nice avatar by the way, Calvin and Hobbes was a great comic strip!

Answer (score 2):

Firefox does not support `document.all` so instead of

```
var obj = document.all.select1;
```

use

```
var obj = document.getElementById("select1");
```

(Your also missing an xmlns)

Answer (score 1):

this work

```
 var obj = document.getElementById("select1");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `document.getElementById` instead of `document.all`. `all` is deprecated, so I'm guessing that is dying when you use XHTML as your doctype.

Comment: To be deprecated it would have had to be standard to start with. It is just an IE4ism.

Comment: @Quentin No, it just has to have been used to be deprecated; it doesn't have to be a standard first. Use of `document.all` is discouraged even when writing pages for IE, so it's deprecated. Also, note that the OP states that this code works on FF without the doctype (quirks mode).